# Overpass API : Loop through cities and find total length of road centerline per city

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to prepare a Overpass QL such a way that it iterate through a list of City Names and find sum of lengths of all the road centerline features which are falling inside the city administrative boundary.

The idea is not to download to entire data rather to get only required total road length per city wise.

1. New York City, New York, USA
2. Toronto, Ontario, Canada
3. Jersey city, New Jersey, USA
4. <City_Name>, <STATE/PROVINCE>,

Above is the example input and below is sample QL with BBOX but need to automate either with overpy python api or writing single overpass QL for entire list of cities.

> [out:json][timeout:25];(way"highway"="primary";way"highway"="secondary";way"highway"="tertiary";way"highway"="unclassified";way"highway"="residential";);(._;>;);out;

Appreciate if someone can give pointers to move ahead.

-Prem